# i want to display all the player of the respective club and have some issue in table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, project

I have a clubs table having field:

```
id,name,est_date,CEO ....
```

i have players table having field:

```
id, name,DOB,height,weight, .....
```

player_histories table:

```
id,player_id,previous_club_id,current_club_id,position, ......
```

club_histories table:

```
club_id, championship_id,status, ...
```

In view page of club_histories, i can show:

```
club name,championship name and status...
```

but i want to show the respective player of club too in club_histories table... how is it posssible???
please reply...

Edited Portion: added code

Routes.php:

```
Route::resource('clubhistories','ClubHistoryController');
```

ClubHistoryController.php:

```
public function show($id,ClubHistory $clubhistories)
{
    $club=$clubhistories->find($id);

    $clubhistories=$clubhistories->getPlayerByCLub();
    return view('pages.singleClub',compact('club','clubhistories'));
}
```

ClubHistoryRepository.php

```
  public function getPlayerByCLub(){
    return $this->makeModel() ->join('clubs', 'clubs.id', '=', 'club_histories.club_id')
        ->join('player_histories','player_histories.current_club_id', '=', 'clubs.id')
        ->join('players', 'players.id', '=', 'player_histories.player_id')
        ->get([
            'clubs.name',
            'player_histories.player_id',
            'players.name',
        ]);
}
```

SingleClub.blade.php:

```
 <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane in active" id="basic">

                        <table class="table table-condensed">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>contact</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>Name:</td>
                                  <td>{!!$club->club->name!!}</td>

                                </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td>Contact:</td>
                                      <td>{!!$club->club->contact_no!!}</td>
                                   </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="players">
                        <table class="table table-condensed">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Player name</th>
                                <th>Position</th> 
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                            @foreach($clubhistories as $clubhistories)
                            <tr>

                                <td> {!! $clubhistories->name!!}   </td>
                                <td>   {!! $clubhistories->position!!} </td>

                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

above join used and solution you have given give a same solution..i want to pass the same id find by clubhistories in club object to clubhistories object so that all the player of club will be shown ..
can you please help me..

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the players in club_histories either through joins (less queries) or Eloquent relationships (simpler looking code).

Using [Eloquent Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) (assuming you've set them up):

```
$histories = ClubHistory::with('players', 'club')->get();

// In your blade view
@foreach ($histories as $history)
    <p>{{ $history->club->name }} won {{ $history->championship_name }}</p>
    <p>Status: {{ $history->status }}
    <div>Player list:
        <ul>
            foreach ($history->players as $player)
                <li>{{ $player->name }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Joins with the query builder:

```
DB::table('club_histories')
    ->join('player_histories',
        'player_histories.current_club_id', '=', 'club_histories.club_id')
    ->join('players', 'players.id', '=', 'player_histories.player_id')
    ->join('club', 'club.id', '=', 'club_histories.club_id')
    ->get([
        'club.name AS clubName',
        'club_histories.championship_name',
        'club_histories.status',
        'player_histories.player_id',
        'players.name AS playerName',
    ]);
```

Note that the above will return one row per player per club_history

EDIT:

After seeing your code, here's a version of the above that should work with your non-standard codebase. Be sure to pass the ID to `getPlayerByClub($id)`.

ClubHistoryRepository.php

```
public function getPlayerByCLub($clubHistoryId) {
    return $this->makeModel()
        ->join('clubs', 'clubs.id', '=', 'club_histories.club_id')
        ->join('player_histories', 'player_histories.current_club_id', '=', 'clubs.id')
        ->join('players', 'players.id', '=', 'player_histories.player_id')
        ->where('club_histories.id', '=', $clubHistoryId)
        ->get([
            'clubs.id',
            'club_histories.championship_name',
            'club_histories.status',
            'player_histories.player_id',
            'clubs.name',
            'players.name',
        ]);
}
```

Comment: i will edit the code... above, I WANT TO display in single page... i am using resourcefull controller

Comment: Ah, I see at least one problem.. I forgot to add "AS" clauses to my answer. You need `club.name AS clubName` and `players.name AS playerName` so that the two 'name' fields don't clash. Then in your blade file you'll be able to do `$clubhistories->clubName` and `$clubhistories->playerName`.

Comment: it shows same solution..it is not getting the clubhistory id...
eg: localhost/fcimsProject/clubhistories/1

Comment: i havent used this line: $histories = ClubHistory::with('players', 'club')->get(); because it gives error of ->with

Comment: It's difficult to help you with this limited information -- I don't know what type of object `ClubHistoryRepository` is, or what this `makeModel()` method is -- they're not standard Laravel. I'll try to update my answer with code that will work though. You're getting all records because you're not using the `$id` in your query with the `->join()` statements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90647/discussion-between-ben-and-sabin-maharjan).